# Zero Inflated Models gene expression

Tags: normalization

I was wondering (searching) when modelling (normalisation) count matrix in scRNAseq data using zero inflated models like the statsmodels.discrete.count_model.ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomial or the poisson one what is generally the response variable (exog) to model it on